# How do I close Dartium after unit test completes

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-unittest

After the unit test completes (success or failure) the Dartium browser remains open. Is there a way to close it from within the test?

Comment: How are you running your tests?  Using karma and karma-dart, the browser should open and close automatically.

Comment: content_shell is another option

Comment: @James I'm just running from the dart editor at the moment. i.e. 'run in Dartium' with my test html & dart file. 
Thanks for the suggestion (and @GünterZöchbauer). I'll likely have to use on of them. There doesn't seem to be anything in native dart (e.g. unittest package) that can tell Dartium to exit after the test runs

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't run a unit test in a browser for a long time